# State undefined when using combineReducers()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I can't get my state when I want to combine my 2 reducers.

All was working when I was using only one reducer but when I tried with combineReducers(), I couldn't get my state anymore.

```
 const initialState = 
{ 
    films: []
}

const filmsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    let nextState;

    switch (action.type)
    {
        [...]
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default filmsReducer;
```

```
const initialState = { checkedCategories: [''] }

const categoriesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    let nextState;

    switch (action.type) {
        [...]
        default :
            return state;
    }
}

export default categoriesReducer;
```

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import films from './films-reducer';
import categories from './categories-reducer';

export default combineReducers({films, categories});
```

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';

export default createStore(rootReducer);
```

Below is where I get an undefined

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

export const Categories = (props) => {
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    const checkedCategories = useSelector(state => state.checkedCategories)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const categoryToggle = (category) => {
        console.log(checkedCategories);
        if (checkedCategories.findIndex(item => item.id === category.id) !== -1)
            return (<div>caca</div>)
    }
[...]
}
```

I got an initialState and a default return for both.

Comment: Can you show where you're using them? Where it's undefined?

Comment: @BrianThompson just did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding `combineReducers` you've changed the structure of your state object.

The structure was previously a single object containing `checkedCategories`. Something like this:

```js
state: {
  checkedCategories: ['']
}
```

But now its something like this:

```js
state: {
  films: {
    films: []
  }, 
  categories: {
    checkedCategories: ['']
  }
}
```

You need to adjust your selectors accordingly:

```
const checkedCategories = useSelector(state => state.categories.checkedCategories)
//                                                   ^ nested one level deeper now
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the name of the level deeper ?

Comment: You named it yourself by passing the object to `combineReducers`: `combineReducers({films, categories});`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try naming your exported combined reducer to rootReducer -

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({films, categories});
```

or if you like verbosity

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({films, categories});

export rootReducer;
```

Good luck and happy hacking.

Comment: A default export can be imported with any name.

Comment: Changing it from default to named will have no effect here

Comment: ah Thanks Brian. It was just a shot in the dark here. I was thinking that if importing rootReducer from a file that is not exporting a rootReducer might have an impact but good to know. The state object definitely changes. I like your answer.

Answer (score 0):

simply after using combineReducer you have change the pattern of useSelector from
useSelector(state => state.checkedCategories)
To
useSelector(state => state.categories.checkedCategories)

because you have to mention from which reducers state u r going to take variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).